# Getting user from SNS EndpointAdded Event

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I'm trying to associate my user's Cognito identity with the SNS endpoints they create when registering for push notifications. I've created a Lambda functions connected to the SNS application's EndpointAdded topic. It is fired whenever an endpoint is created, but it does not include any information I can see that I can use to associate the endpoint to a user.

I see many examples where people are adding the user ID as custom user data, but this allows any user to sign up for any other user's notifications. Is there a more secure way to make this association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you front registering the endpoint with Lambda or APIGateway and you use SigV4 credentials vended by Cognito to make the call, the context passed in will contain the Cognito Identity Id extracted from the credentials that made the call.  This will ensure that the identity id you associate with the endpoint hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: I am not, I'm calling CreatePlatformEndpoint from a mobile app using Cognito credentials. You are suggesting creating the endpoint from a Lambda, then (separately) perform the association, rather than use the endpoint created topic?

Comment: Right, I'm saying there is no secure way only from the mobile app.  You have 2 options, either call CreatePlatformEndpoint through APIG/Lambda and do the association there, or call CreatePlatformEndpoint from the mobile device and do the association with a subsequent call to APIG/Lambda.

Comment: For some reason I had it in my head that the endpoint registration ought to happen on the actual device. Doing this in a Lambda function is much simpler and allows me to drop the SimpleNotificationService dependancies.